# Moment Matching Scenario Generation in R

Tags: r, while-loop, finance, scenarios, r-portfolioanalytics

I am working on a portfolio optimazion algorithm and part of the problem consists in generating moment matching scenario.

My choice due to its simplicity and quickness was to go through paper ["An algorithm for moment-matching scenario generation with application to financial portfolio optimization" (Ponomareva, Roman and Date)](http://bura.brunel.ac.uk/bitstream/2438/10045/1/FullText.pdf).

The problem is that even though the mathematics are very simple, I am stuck by the fact that some of probability weights `pi` are negative even though the formulas in the paper should ensure otherwise. If I put a loop to run the algorithm until it finds a positive combination it essentially runs forever.

I put the bit of code based on the paper were things get stuck:

```
dummy1 = 0
while (dummy1 <=0 | dummy1 >= 1) {
  dummy1 = round(rnorm(1, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.25), 2)
}

diag.cov.returns = diag(cov.returns)
Z = dummy1 * sqrt (diag.cov.returns) #Vector Z according to paper formula

ZZT = Z %*% t(Z)
LLT = cov.returns - ZZT
L = chol(LLT) #cholesky decomposition to get matrix L

s = sample (1:5, 1)
F1 = 0
F2 = -1
S = (2*N*s)+3

while (((4*F2)-(3*F1*F1)) < 0) {      
  #Gamma = (2*s*s)*(((N*mean.fourth) - (0.75*(sum(Z^4)* (N*mean.third/sum(Z^3))^2)))/sum(L^4))
  #Gamma is necessary if we want to get p from Uniform Distribution
  #U = runif(s, 0, 1)
  U = rgamma(s, shape = 1, scale = ((1/exp(1)):1))

  #p = (s*(N/Gamma)) + ((1/(2*N*s)) - (s/(N*Gamma)))*U
  p = (-log(U, base = exp(1)))
  p = p/(((2*sum(p))+max(p))*N*s) #this is the array expected to have positive and bounded between 0 and 1
  q1 = 1/p
  pz = p

  p[s+1] = (1-(2*N*sum(p))) #extra point necessary to get the 3 moment mathcing probabilities
  
  F1 = (N*mean.third*sqrt(p[s+1]))/(sum(Z^3))
  F2 = p[s+1]*(((N*mean.fourth) - (1/(2*s*s))*sum(L^4)*(sum(1/p)))/sum(Z^4))
  
}
alpha = (0.5*F1) + 0.5*sqrt((4*F2)-(3*F1*F1))
beta = -(0.5*F1) + 0.5*sqrt((4*F2)-(3*F1*F1))

w1 = 1/(alpha*(alpha+beta))
w2 = 1/(beta*(alpha+beta))
w0 = 1 - (1/(alpha*beta))

P = rep(pz, 2*N) #Vector with Probabilities starting from p + 3 extra probabilities to match third and fourth moments
P[(2*N*s)+1] = p[s+1]*w0
P[(2*N*s)+2] = p[s+1]*w1
P[(2*N*s)+3] = p[s+1]*w2
```

Unfortunately I cannot discolose the input dataset containing funds returns. However I can surely be more specific. Starting from a `data.frame()` containing N assets' returns (in my case there 11 funds and monthly returns from 30/01/2001 to 30/09/2020). Once the mean returns, covariance matrix, central third and fourth moments (NOT skewness and kurtosis) and the averages are computed. The algorithm follows as I have reported in the problem. The point where i get stuck is that p takes also negative values. This is a problem since the first s elements of p are later used as probabilities in P.
I hope that in this way the problem is more clear. I also want to add that in the paper the data used by the authors is reported, unfortunately to import them in R would be necessary to import them manually. However I repeat any `data.frame()` containing assets' returns will do.

Comment: Could you post a minimum reproducible example, e.g. by supplying some input data. Also, could you add some comment to the code to describe what each step is trying to do? Which variable do you expect to be positive?

Comment: I edited the text in order to be more clear and specific. I realised that in fact I gave very few information about the problem. Hope it will help.